# How exactly are we proving that modus ponens is valid?

Tags: proof-verification, logic, definition, propositional-calculus

This is being done in the context of a Hilbert system in propositional logic.

But let's assume we've already proven all the axioms are tautologies / will always be true.

How then are we showing that modus ponens is also valid? (or is valid the wrong word to use here? Normally, "valid" for a statement means the logic holds IF the premises were true, but premises being true is what makes it actually sound... but when it comes to inference rules I don't know the terminology)

$P, (P \to Q) \vdash Q$

Is this strictly an informal "look at the truth tables and reason it out" kind of thing?

i.e. if we assume $P$ is true and $P \to Q$ is true because they are each reducible to either true axioms or true atomic propositions, then we know $P \to Q = \top$ becomes $\top \to Q = \top$. And in the truth tables for $\to$, this only has one solution, i.e. where $Q = \top$, therefore modus ponens holds? Or are we now showing that $P, (P \to Q) \vDash Q$?

I mean is that it? Or is it a more formal approach? I get totally lost when it comes to understanding and manipulating / proving things with these metalogical symbols.

Comment: We prove the *soundness* of the inference rules (like e.g. *modus ponens*). See the post [Method of Proving Soundness of Propositional Logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636615/method-of-proving-soundness-of-propositional-logic) as well as your previous post [Soundness vs completeness, am I understanding ? And proving soundness ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910909/soundness-vs-completeness-am-i-understanding-and-proving-soundness)

Comment: Is valid then the same as $\vDash$?

Comment: The [Double turnstile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_turnstile#Meaning) symbol has two uses (strictly linked) in logic. $\vDash \varphi$ means that formula $\varphi$ is *valid* (true in every interpretation). $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$ means that formula $\varphi$ is *logical consequence* of the set $\Gamma$ of formulas. See your previous post [How is my understanding of ⊢,⊨,→, etc.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910093/how-is-my-understanding-of-vdash-vdash-to-etc)

Comment: See also your previous post [Valid vs. sound.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2906608/valid-vs-sound-and-if-these-differences-matter-in-syntax-vs-semantics-metalo)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281208/what-is-the-difference-between-a-sound-argument-and-a-valid-argument which seems to contradict this definition

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA From your old post: "An argument is valid if and only if it takes a form that makes it impossible for the premises to be true and the conclusion nevertheless to be false. **It is not required that a valid argument have premises that are actually true, but to have premises that, if they were true, would guarantee the truth of the argument's conclusion.**"